# How do flames neutralize a static charge?

Tags: electrostatics, plasma-physics

I was working with a demonstration galvanometer recently when it accidentally picked up a static charge from me lightly rubbing my hand across it.  The case was made of a clear plastic.  My attempts at neutralizing it just by touching it with my hand again and touching it with a grounded wire were ineffective.  I remembered some advice that a flame could be used to remove the static charge and held it near the flame from a Bunsen burner.  In a second or two it was back in working order with no sign of static charge.

How does a flame neutralize a static electric charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flame has many charged particles (ions and electrons) within it.
THose with the appropriate sign are attracted to a charged object and neutralise it.

There is a standard demonstration to show that there are charges of both signs within a flame.
A candle is placed between two vertical conducting plates which have a potential difference of about 1000 V across them.
When the voltage is switched on it is found that the flame spreads out because the ions in the flame are attracted towards the conducting plates.

Comment: In addition, there will be a film built up on the surface (mainly hydrocarbon crud) that will be pretty decent at dissipating charge.